# Why no event is triggered when I press Enter in aframe-super-keyboard?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am using aframe-super-keyboard and I am trying to get the input text from it.
I used this: https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-super-keyboard/issues/18, but the event is not triggered when I press Enter.

I also put multipleInputs: true but when I press enter the keyboard is closed even with this.

This is my html:

```
<a-entity id="hand" hand-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="keyboard" super-keyboard="hand: #hand; imagePath: ./textures/; multipleInputs: true;" my-keyboard position="0 1.076 -0.5" rotation="-30 0 0"></a-entity>
```

And this is my script:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('my-keyboard', {
init: function(){
  this.el.addEventListener('superkeyboardinput', function(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
    alert(event.value); // the text
  });
 }
});
```

I also saw here (https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-super-keyboard/blob/master/dist/aframe-super-keyboard.js) in the code that there is a button called 'Enter' and another one called 'Insert'. What is the difference? I don't understand which one is 'Insert'.

Comment: It is best to not just link sources when asking questions. For instance, your first link is already pointing to a 404 page. Try to put all relevant info directly into your post.

Comment: I edited the link with one that I hope will not disappear; anyway, what is in that link is exactly my code below; I just wanted to show that I found it as an answer and I used it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

The main problem is that in the documentation the version for the script is 1.0.0:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-super-keyboard@1.0.0/dist/aframe-super-keyboard.min.js"></script>
```

This has to be replaced with 2.1.0. Then this will NOT work with
`hand-controls`, but will work with `laser-controls`.